# Java When outputting String and method return, why does method return output first?

Tags: java, methods, output

In the code below, if the string `"Mult"` comes before the `test1(4)` method call, why does the method output before the string? And why does it bounce form outputting the first part of the method, then leaves the method to output the string, then returns to the method to output the method's return value?

code:

```
public class Scratch{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Mult:" + test1(4));
  }

  public static int test1(int n){
    System.out.println("N:" + n);
    return n*2;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
N:4
Mult:8
```

Comment: You are calling the method and inside that method it is printing out something first so hence why you have that output

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking about the 1"--------------------\nN:"` string inside the method.  I'm asking about the `"Mult:"` string in the `main` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note is when you use the `+` with two operands where one of the two operands is a `String`, the result of the expression is a `String`.

Therefore, in the following method invocation expression

```
System.out.println("Mult:" + test1(4));
```

you are invoking the [`PrintStream#println(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) since `out` is a variable of type `PrintStream`. Note how the method accepts a single `String` argument. Therefore, the `String`  has to be resolved from the `String` concatenation of

```
"Mult:" + test1(4)
```

For that to happen, the `test1(4)` method has to be executed.

```
public static int test1(int n){
    System.out.println("N:" + n);
    return n*2;
}
```

This method again uses `PrintStream#println(String)` but with the argument

```
"N:" + n
```

This is another `String` concatenation that produces the `String` value

```
"N:4"
```

for this particular invocation. The produced `String` value is then used as an argument to the `println(..)` method which outputs it to your program's standard output.

The method then returns the value `8`, since `4 * 2 = 8`.

That return value is the value of invoking the `test1(4)` method. So

```
System.out.println("Mult:" + test1(4));
```

is equivalent to

```
System.out.println("Mult:" + 8);
```

Then `String` concatenation occurs, transforming

```
"Mult:" + 8
```

into the `String` value

```
"Mult:8"
```

That `String` is then used as the single argument to the `println(..)` method which outputs it to your program's standard output.

Answer (score 3):

> In the code below, if the string "Mult" comes before the test1(4) method call, why does the method output before the string?

Because you're *calling* the method before you're calling `System.out.println` with the "Mult:" part.

Basically, your code is equivalent to:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int tmp = test1(4); // This prints N:4 
  System.out.println("Mult:" + tmp);
}
```

If you think about it, the `test1` method *has* to be completed before the string concatenation can occur (otherwise we can't know what the right hand side of the concatenation operator is), and the string concatenation has to occur before the `System.out.println` call can occur (otherwise we can't know what we're going to print). Make sense/

Comment: Perhaps also saying that the System.out.println is not executed until the last `)` might help.

Comment: @Quincunx: I'm not sure it would in this case, to be honest.

Comment: I meant println, not method. But viewing methods as only executing when we reach the corresponding `)` helps to figure out execution order. Basically, the `)` "sends" the arguments to the method, so no arguments are sent before it.

Comment: @Quincunx: I personally think my answer already clarifies that enough. You can always add your own answer, of course.

Comment: @Quincunx I'm beginning to understand that execution and concatenation are not independent of one another.  I've understood almost from the beginning of my inquiry that the method must execute first.  But why does concatenation order follow execution order if I'm asking it to concatenate in a different order?

Comment: @StuartKuredjian: What do you mean by "asking it to concatenate in a different order"? Both operands of the string concatenation operator must be evaluated before the concatenation can take place... and in your case, the evaluation of the second operand has the side effect of printing "N:4".

Comment: @JonSkeet got it.  I was overlooking that the internal `println` call was being executed as the `test1()` method was being evaluated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When

```
System.out.println("Mult:" + test1(4));
```

is run, test1(4) must be evaluated before it can be System.out.println'd.
So, the JVM will run the following:

```
evalate result of test1(4) {
    print ("N:" + 4);
    return 2*4;
}
evalate result of "Mult:" + returnedValue {
    print("Multi:" + returnedValue);
}
```

The JVM cannot print something before it knows its value. In this case, test1(4) get evaluated first so the JVM knows what to print out (the return value).

You could also complete the task this way>>

```
int result = test1(4); //This prints out 4 and evaluates to 8
System.out.println("Mult: " + result); //This concats "Mult: " and 8 after converting it to of type String
```

Comment: OK i think I got it.  So `test1()` is executed.  Within `test1()` is a call to println, so it does.  But the method isn't being asked to output the return value; only use its result when called by the `main` method. Then when the concatenation is called in the order I specified, it does so with the internal `println` already having been output.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Mult:" + test1(4)
```

The above line is an expression whose value is the concatenation of `"Mult:"`, and of the result of `test1(4)`. So, to be able to know the result of this concatenation, `test1(4)` is executed. This execution prints `"N:4"`, and then multiplies n by 2, returning 8. 8 is then concatenated with `"Mult:"`, and the result is printed.

Comment: I only partially understand. If you're saying that in any given expression, methods are executed before the string, OK.  But from what you explained, I'm understanding that BECAUSE the expression's result relies on the calculation, the result of the calculation is appended to the concatenation first, and this logic doesn't make sense to me.  The expression itself is saying to first append `"Mult:"` to the concat. and THEN execute the method and THEN append the result of the method.  So there is still some logic that I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It obvious.If a method does not have its arguments calculated it cant be completed.
In your case the println method must have its arguments computed before it can be executed. So the function call to test1 method is made which completes first.  Then the statement in main is executed.

Comment: I understand the logic that an expression can't be finalized in all parts are calculated, but I don't understand what the append order has to do with the calculation order.  For that matter, I don't even understand why the method needs to calculate first?  The command is to print the string, then append the return value of the method.  Why can't it append the string, then calculate and append the return value of the method?

Comment: The println method needs an argument after the string argument and you have a method call inplace of the  argument.your println method can nit be exexuted until its has a valid argument.thus it waits for the methid call to be executed then only it can be exexuted.Read a bit about compilers and its phases.